# Excel JavaScript API: find parent objects

Tags: excel, office-js

So I’m working my way through this very under-developed JavaScript API in an Office App, and I’m trying to figure out how to get an objects parent. Specifically, how to get a worksheet from a range, or a worksheet from a table, but could also be a worksheet from a chart, workbook from a worksheet, etc. I have yet to find any sample code which does this. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please don't vote to close this. The Microsoft team directed the OP to ask this question here instead of in an email so that the answer could be shared with the community.

Comment: Thanks for your code Michael! That very much works for me. I would still like a Parent object for objects.

Comment: Who downvoted this question? If you folks don't understand that this is about a new, emerging technology, and that this is a dialog directly with Mircrosoft, just stay away from the question.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Gabriel Royer's answer, here is some code sample:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    var worksheet = range.worksheet;
    worksheet.load("name");
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        app.showNotification("Sheet name", worksheet.name);
    });
}).catch(function(e) {
    app.showNotification("Error", e);
});
```

Of course the above sample is a little silly, since you could as well have done

```js
var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
```

But the sample gets much more realistic if you instead use a named range:

```js
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.names.getItem("MyNamedRange").getRange();
    var worksheet = range.getRange();
    worksheet.load("name");
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        app.showNotification("Sheet name", worksheet.name);
    });
}).catch(function(e) {
    app.showNotification("Error", e);
});
```

For a table, you could figure out what sheet it's on by doing:

```js
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    var table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem("Table1");
    var worksheet = table.getRange().worksheet;
    worksheet.load("name");
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        app.showNotification("Sheet name", worksheet.name);
    });
}).catch(function(e) {
    app.showNotification("Error", e);
});
```

PS: Note: The above code uses the `app.showNotification(title, text)` method, which is part of the standard Visual Studio template for Office add-ins.  If you are not using the template, just replace any such call with `console.log(title + " " + text")`

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a common mechanism to get an object's parent, there is a way in some cases to do so:

- `Range` has a [`worksheet` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598656.aspx) (an example can be found at the end of the page)
- `Table` allows you to get its range through its [`getRange()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598663.aspx), which you can then use its `worksheet` property to get the table's parent worksheet.
- `Worksheet` - the APIs are for a single workbook, so the `workbook` property on the context is guaranteed to be the worksheet's parent.

`Chart` on the other hand doesn't have any back pointer to its parent so there isn't much you can do in this case. While your feedback is duly noted, feel free to request such API/mechanism on the [Office Extensibility Platform's UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js).

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Posted to UserVoice: http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/10775388-provide-a-common-parent-object-in-the-javascript-a

Thanks for the feedback Gabriel, much appreciated.

Comment: Gabriel, I tried implementing what you said to no avail. I'm trying to get the worksheet of a table, specifically. I have this line...

            var tableRange = clickedTableName.getRange;
            var tableSheet = tableRange.

But I do not have a worksheet object for the range. How do I get the worksheet object of a table? This would be simplified if I had a Parent object of objects, like we have in about every other office extensibility story.

Comment: I've modified my answer to clarify that you need the get the table range's worksheet if you want the table's worksheet.

Comment: @ZackBarresse, when you use a "get"-prefixed method, you need to do the function invocation.  That is, you need the parentheses at the end of 
"getRange()", not "getRange".  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score -1):

```
## Loading the existing worksheet ##

----------
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
  var sheet=ctx.workbook.names.getItem("SheetName").getRange("Specify your range");
  sheet.load("name");
  return ctx.sync().then(function() {
    console.log("Sheet name", sheet.name); //getting the sheet name
    sheet.activate();
  });
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log("Error", e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It still doesn't really work in a real-world scenario, because the sheet name will most likely not (ever?) be known at run-time. That's the beauty of an add-in, which, in the case of Office Add-Ins, are workbook-based atm, so the only real known is the Workbook object. And even in the case of a known workbook [object], you may not know the name (users do crazy things, like save copies... crazy users).